# How to convert Html.Html msg to Html.Html Msg?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to write a TabControl in Elm as follows

```
module TabControl exposing (..)

import Html 
import Html.Attributes as Attributes
import Html.Events
import Array

type Msg
    = OnSelectedTabChanged
    | NoOp

type alias Model msg =
    { tabs : List (Tab msg)
    , selectedIndex : Int    
    }

constructor : Model msg
constructor =
    { tabs = []
    , selectedIndex = 0
    }

type alias Tab msg =
    { title : String
    , content : Html.Html msg 
    }

withTab : Tab msg -> Model msg -> (Model msg)
withTab tab model = 
    { model | tabs = model.tabs ++ [tab] }

render : Model msg -> Html.Html msg
render model =
    let 
        header = renderTabHeaders model
        content = renderSelectedTabContent model
    in
    Html.div [] [ header, content ]

renderTabHeaders : Model msg -> Html.Html msg
renderTabHeaders model =
    Html.div []    
    [
        Html.ul []        
        (
            model.tabs 
                |> List.map (\(tab) -> renderTabHeader tab)           
        )
    ]

renderTabHeader : Tab msg -> Html.Html msg
renderTabHeader tab =
    Html.li [Html.Events.onClick OnSelectedTabChanged] [Html.text tab.title]                        

renderSelectedTabContent : Model msg -> Html.Html msg
renderSelectedTabContent model =
    let 
        array = 
            Array.fromList model.tabs

        item = 
            Array.get model.selectedIndex array
    in
        case item of 
            Just value ->
                value.content
            Nothing ->
                Html.text ""
```

which is rendered by

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import TabControl

main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = 0, update = update, view = view }

view model =
  div []  
  [  
    TabControl.constructor
    |> TabControl.withTab (TabControl.Tab "title 1" (Html.text "html 1"))
    |> TabControl.withTab (TabControl.Tab "title 2" (Html.text "html 2"))
    |> TabControl.render
  ]
```

However, I can't seem to get the return types correct.

If I refactor `renderTabHeader : Tab msg -> Html.Html msg` to `renderTabHeader : Tab msg -> Html.Html Msg` then

```
Something is off with the body of the `renderTabHeaders` definition:

This `div` call produces:

    Html.Html Msg

But the type annotation on `renderTabHeaders` says it should be:

    Html.Html msg
```

if I don't then

```
Something is off with the body of the `renderTabHeader` definition:

This `li` call produces:

    Html.Html Msg

But the type annotation on `renderTabHeader` says it should be:

    Html.Html msg
```

If I make every function return Html.Html Msg then

```
Something is off with the 1st branch of this `case` expression:

67|                 value.content
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The value at .content is a:

    Html.Html msg

But the type annotation on `renderSelectedTabContent` says it should be:

    Html.Html Msg
```

How can I have elements in a div, some of which return `Html.Html msg` and some of which return `Html.Html Msg`? Or alternatively, how can I convert between `Html.Html msg` and `Html.Html Msg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to expose your `Msg` type, you'll need the user of your module to supply a function which translates your `Msg` into their `msg`.

So, if the top-level `Msg` type looks like this:

```
type Msg
    = NoOp
    | TabControlMsg TabControl.Msg
    | SomethingElse
```

Then render can take a function which accepts a `TabControl.Msg` and returns a `Msg`, which, in this case, would be the `TabControlMsg` constructor.

```
view model =
  div []  
  [  
    TabControl.constructor
    |> TabControl.withTab (TabControl.Tab "title 1" (Html.text "html 1"))
    |> TabControl.withTab (TabControl.Tab "title 2" (Html.text "html 2"))
    |> TabControl.render TabControlMsg
  ]
```

Then you would adjust the code in your module to use that function:

```
render : (Msg -> msg) -> Model msg -> Html.Html msg
render toMsg model =
    let 
        header = renderTabHeaders model
        content = renderSelectedTabContent toMsg model
    in
    Html.div [] [ header, content ]

renderSelectedTabContent : (Msg -> msg) -> Model msg -> Html.Html msg
renderSelectedTabContent toMsg model =
    let 
        array = 
            Array.fromList model.tabs

        item = 
            Array.get model.selectedIndex array
    in
        case item of 
            Just value ->
                Html.map toMsg value.content
            Nothing ->
                Html.text ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. so I can map value.content to return a Msg like so

```
renderSelectedTabContent : Model msg -> Html.Html Msg
renderSelectedTabContent model =
    let 
        array = 
            Array.fromList model.tabs

        item = 
            Array.get model.selectedIndex array
    in
        case item of 
            Just value ->
                Html.map (\_ -> NoOp) value.content
            Nothing ->
                Html.text ""
```